# Easily import element from another website

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to import an element from another website to make a live preview on my own website, eg what a new post might look like. I've tried the following approaches:

- [SnappySnippet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/snappysnippet/blfngdefapoapkcdibbdkigpeaffgcil) - this however merely copies the computed style,
  leaving things like width and height fixed
- Copying the element and the website's CSS file, then removing unused selectors using [CSS remove and combine](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-remove-and-combine/cdfmaaeapjmacolkojefhfollmphonoh?hl=en-GB) - this however imports several unwanted selectors as well, impacting other parts of my website

Is there a clever way to do this, or am I left to `iframe` or manual porting?

Comment: @Downvoters care to explain what's wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at html5's article tag?

Answer (score 0):

Approaches...

Use iframe.

Use server to fecth,render, then display on client.

Use api if possible.

If other site is yours then jus load it in iframe and copy it as it wont be limited cross domain limitation